# C - Help printing a member of a returned Struct

Tags: c, linux, struct

I want to return a struct and print one of its members in main.

I am getting this error when trying to compile:

```
Main.c: In function ‘main’:
Main.c:8:2: error: invalid use of undefined type ‘struct busRoute’
```

Any help would be appreciated. I don't see why what I'm trying to do won't compile.

**BusRoute.c**

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include "BusRoute.h"

    struct busRoute {
        int busRouteNumber;
        char *startingLocation;
        char *endingLocation;
        char driverName[36];
    } route[STRUCT_SIZE] = {0};

    //retrieves route info
    struct busRoute getBusRouteInfo(unsigned int index)
    {
        return route[index];
    }

    void setStruct()
    {
        route[2].busRouteNumber = 5;
    }
```

**Main.c File**

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include "BusRoute.h"

    int main()
    {
        setStruct();
        printf("%d",getBusRouteInfo(2).busRouteNumber);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `struct busRoute` should be defined in `BusRoute.h`, not `BusRoute.c`, if you want to use it in `main.c`. And you *do* want to use it in `main.c`, if your `getBusRouteInfo()` function returns one. Without `main.c` being able to see this definition, it doesn't know that `struct busRoute` even *has* a member named `busRouteNumber`, let alone how to get at it, so that's why compilation fails.

Your other option is to define a function like `getBusRouteInfoRouteNumber(2)`, which will return the appropriate member indirectly. That way, `main.c` doesn't need to know anything about the actual `struct busRoute`.

Comment: My Struct needs to be kept in BusRoute.c, but your second solution would work. I was hoping to avoid having a Get function for each member though.

Comment: Depending on your interface, you might not need one for each member, and generally shouldn't default to doing this. Your interface should provide the logical operations you need, which may or may not correspond to individual members of your data structures.